# Making checkbox menu dropdown on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, dropdown

I haven't done any HTML or CSS in about 5 years and I'm trying to get back into it to help out a local business.  I've created a menu with DIV classes and CSS styling but I can't figure out how to get my menu's to expand on hover instead of click.

I've already tried adding lines like
    .nav:hover.item{display: block;}
to no avail.

```html
     <html>
      
     <style type="text/css">
      /*Global*/
      html,body {
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       font-family: sans-serif;
       position:top
      }
     
      
     .multi-level, .item ul, .nav
      
      input[type="checkbox"]{
      display: none;
         }
      #menu:checked ~ .multi-level, .item input:checked ~ ul {
       
       display:block;
      }

      label:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        label {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        z-index: 3;
        position: relative;
        }
        .nav {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkblue;
     color:white;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD8DC;
        }

        .nav ul, .nav li, label {
        line-height: 25px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 2em;
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 100;
        width: 100%;
        }
        .item ul {
        padding: 0 0.25em;
        }
        .nav li a {
        line-height: 25px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 4em;
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: lightblue;
        font-weight: 100;
        }
      
     </style>
        <body>
     <div class="nav">
     <input type="checkbox" id="menu"/>
      <label for="menu">&#9776;</label>
        <div class="multi-level">
       <div class="item">
       <input type="checkbox" id="A"/>
        <label for="A">Resources</label>
        
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li><div class="sub-item">
         <input type="checkbox" id="A-B"/>
         <label for="A-B">Location Information</label>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FacInfo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Specialty Phone/Pool List</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Primary Care Direct Dial #s</a></li>
          
         </ul>
         
         </div></li>
        </ul>    
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="B"/>
        <label for="B">Scheduling</label>
       <ul>
        <li><div class="sub-item">
         <input type="checkbox" id="B-A"/>
         <label for="B-A">Primary Care</label>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Cold/Flu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">UTI / Pink Eye</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Trauma / Inuries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Common Injections</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nurse Visits</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Depo Injections</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cortisone Injections</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Physicals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">All Job Aids</a></li>
         </ul>
         
         </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      
      
      </div>

     </div>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You should be putting your CSS *above* the HTML -- The `Cascading` in `CSS` is all about *where* the styles are.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using a checkbox instead of a `<a href=" ">` tag or a button?

Comment: checkbox better solution because it is responsive. you can't hover on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not far from a working solution. The easiest would be, near to what you wrote, is `.nav:hover ul {display:block}`, but that opens the whole menu including all submenus at once. It feels a bit better, to open only the submenu for the item that is hovered:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: top;
}

.multi-level,
.item ul,
.nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

#menu:checked ~ .multi-level,
.item input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}

/* changes */
.nav:hover .multi-level,
.item:hover > ul,
.sub-item:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
/* /changes */

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD8DC;
}

.nav ul,
.nav li,
label {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
}

.item ul {
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}

.nav li a {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 4em;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightblue;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu"/>
  <label for="menu">&#9776;</label>
  <div class="multi-level">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="A"/>
      <label for="A">Resources</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><div class="sub-item">
          <input type="checkbox" id="A-B"/>
          <label for="A-B">Location Information</label>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">FacInfo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Specialty Phone/Pool List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Primary Care Direct Dial #s</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div></li>
      </ul>               
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="B"/>
      <label for="B">Scheduling</label>
      <ul>
        <li><div class="sub-item">
          <input type="checkbox" id="B-A"/>
          <label for="B-A">Primary Care</label>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Cold/Flu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">UTI / Pink Eye</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trauma / Inuries</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Common Injections</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nurse Visits</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Depo Injections</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cortisone Injections</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Physicals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Job Aids</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With that it is a bit tricky to open the "Scheduling" submenu. But it works, most of the time. And you get to do it without JS, so you're somehow limited. But for most of the time, it works pretty well...